# Entity Framework - tracking changes on non-virtual property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, proxy

I'm writing because currently I'm trying to implement object change tracking on a sample class. I got into using proxies and this approach fits my needs. 
Definition of a class where methods and properties are defined as virtual, afterwards proxy creation suits me.

But apart from that, I am really curious how Entity Framework (with a code-first approach) manages to track changes on an object where property is NOT defined as virtual.

I do understand that creation a proxy (without defining an interface; ef does not require that) is not possible. So how does EF track changes? If I am right and creation of a proxy is not possible, so how does it work?

Does it compare object state to the database on save action, or get changes?

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the object is in the context there are 2 copies of the state. It's used also for optimistic concurrency.

**EDIT**
It means, that Entity compares the object which I modified to its copy like property by property.

Comment: Does it mean, that Entity compares the object which I modified to its copy like property by property?

Comment: Yes. You can also retrieve the collection of the modified properties via GetModifiedProperties (view MSDN). Thinking about this implementation, comparing 2 values is probably slower than checking a boolean but probably an implementation with the proxy (accessing an overrided object, Handling and checking a boolean) could be slower than comparing properties when save.